# Exception thrown related to LiveData and NavigationView during Android app start-up

Tags: android

I have developed an app with a NavigationView that has a handful of MenuItems in it, including one that enables the user to log in or out of the app using Google's one-tap login flow:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/NavigationLogInOut"
    android:icon="@drawable/material_login"
    android:orderInCategory="95"
    android:title="@string/button_log_in" />
```

I have a MutableLiveData to control the enabled/disabled status of the menu item, so that it can be temporarily disabled while a sign-in is currently in progress:

```
public final MutableLiveData<Boolean> logInOutEnabled = new MutableLiveData<>(false);
```

I have the following observer in my activity's OnCreate method:

```
logInOutEnabled.observe(
    this,
    (enabled) -> {
        application.logger.d(
            "Log In/Out Enabled: " + enabled
        );

        logInOutMenuItem.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
);
```

When the app first starts up, I see the relevant debug information in Logcat:

```
08:34:29.350 13869-13869  D  Log In/Out Enabled: false
```

This never causes an crash.

The last thing to happen during onCreate() is to check to see if I have a cached credential for the user, and if I do, I update the observable accordingly:

```
if (!isLoggedIn()) {
    // start the login flow here
} else {
    activity.application.logInOutEnabled.postValue(true);
}
```

I can see that this works, because in the log I see the following, immediately after the previous log entry:

```
08:34:29.664 13869-13869  D  Log In/Out Enabled: true
```

Immediately after, the app crashes about 50% of the time with the following stack trace, and I cannot figure out what's happening:

```
08:34:29.722 13869-13869  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                             Process: com.company.game, PID: 13869
                             java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 6(offset:6).state:7 com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuView{d4afb4b VFED.V... ......ID 0,0-640,1632 #7f0900d2
                             app:id/design_navigation_view}, adapter:com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter@e3e4641, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@131e7e6, context:com.company.game.GameActivity@9fccb96
                                at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6183)
                                at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
                                at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
                                at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
                                at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
                                at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
                                at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
                                at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
                                at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
                                at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23693)
                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23693)
                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
                                at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1287)
                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23693)
                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
                                at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23693)
                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23693)
                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1891)
                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1729)
                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1638)
                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23693)
                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23693)
                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1891)
                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1729)
                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1638)
                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23693)
                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:799)
                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23693)
                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6413)
                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3999)
                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3372)
                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2328)
                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9087)
                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1231)
                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1239)
08:34:29.724 13869-13869  E     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:899)
                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:832)
                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1214)
                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

At this point that this exception is thrown, we can see that updating the menu item's enabled property has already completed successfully one time.  Why does updating the menu item's enabled property cause this crash during the second time?

If I comment out the setEnabled() line in the observer, the application does not crash.

I assume that the NavigationView uses a RecyclerView to show its menu items, but no menu items are added or removed in between the two calls to setEnabled().  Even if they were, the two calls to setEnabled() refer to the exact same MenuItem, so I fail to see how this could be affecting the MenuItem's position in the RecyclerView.

Comment: I am regularly seeing a similar crash, which may be related to removing menu items at runtime (I check to see if a user has upgraded, and then remove the "upgrade" menu item if so).  `navMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_upgrade).setVisible(false);` Maybe it's better just to leave the menu always visible, just thought it was cleaner to remove it.